# Creating an edit button(to-do APP) JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I am complete beginner in JavaScript, I attended to make a to-do App, however when I get into edit button, I just run out of ideas, tried with input but seems everything to go wrong, I am stuck when i try to replace the edited item with the new value.
Any ideas or a tutorial would be really helpful!
My code is this:

```js
 const addButton = document.querySelector('#addButton');
    const inputTask = document.querySelector('#inputTask');
    const taskList = document.querySelector('#taskList');
    const form = document.querySelector('#taskForm');
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const task = inputTask.value;
        if (!task) {
            alert('Please write down a task');
        } else {
            const newLi = document.createElement('li');
            newLi.innerText = task;
            newLi.setAttribute('li', 'readonly');
            taskList.append(newLi);
            
            // this is the delete button:
            const deleteButton = document.createElement('button')
            deleteButton.innerText = "delete";
            newLi.appendChild(deleteButton);
            deleteButton.addEventListener('click', deleting)
    
            // this is the edit button:
    
            const editButton = document.createElement('button');
            editButton.innerText= "EDIT";
            newLi.appendChild(editButton);
            editButton.addEventListener('click', editing);
            
        };
        inputTask.value = "" ; 
        
     });
    
    // delete button make up
    
    function deleting(){
        let forDelete = this.parentElement
        taskList.removeChild(forDelete);
    };
    
    // edit button make up
    
    function editing() {
        let forEdit = this.parentElement;
        let input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'text';
        input.value = 
    
        forEdit.replaceWith(input);
    
        editButton.textContent = 'save';
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /> -->
        <title>to-DO list</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>To-DO</h1>
        <form id="taskForm">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Write a task..." id="inputTask" />
          <input type="submit" value="Add" id="addButton" />
        </form>
        <ol id="taskList">
          TASKS
        </ol>
    
        <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this answer be useful .

in my answer i added new tag (`span`) for todos content. and i add `input` tag when is clicked on `edit` button for editing todo. with `onblur` changes saves.

```js
const addButton = document.querySelector("#addButton");
const inputTask = document.querySelector("#inputTask");
const taskList = document.querySelector("#taskList");
const form = document.querySelector("#taskForm");

form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const task = inputTask.value;
  if (!task) {
    alert("Please write down a task");
  } else {
    const newLi = document.createElement("li");
    const toDoContent = document.createElement("span"); // new tag for to-dos content
    toDoContent.innerText = task;
    newLi.append(toDoContent);
    newLi.setAttribute("li", "readonly");
    taskList.append(newLi);

    // this is the delete button:
    const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    deleteButton.innerText = "delete";
    newLi.appendChild(deleteButton);
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleting);

    // this is the edit button:

    const editButton = document.createElement("button");
    editButton.innerText = "EDIT";
    newLi.appendChild(editButton);
    editButton.addEventListener("click", (e) =>
      editing(e.target.parentElement)
    );
  }
  inputTask.value = "";
});

// delete button make up

function deleting() {
  let forDelete = this.parentElement;
  taskList.removeChild(forDelete);
}

// edit button make up

function editing(liTag) {
  let liContent = liTag.querySelector("span");

  let input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.value = liContent.textContent;
  liTag.append(input);
  input.focus();
  input.addEventListener("blur", () => {
    liContent.innerHTML = input.value;
    input.remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<h1>To-DO</h1>
<form id="taskForm">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Write a task..." id="inputTask" />
  <input type="submit" value="Add" id="addButton" />
</form>
<ol id="taskList">
  TASKS
</ol>
```

Comment: It is working, let me ask you, if i would like to save changes on enter instead of clicking edit again, i need to add eventListener with the keys to javascript?

Comment: yes , add an event listener on `keypress` and check if `keyCode == 13` then save the edit

Answer (score 1):

You might not need an edit button at all. I think the "contenteditable" attribute makes any element user editable. If you *really* want an edit button, you can make the button toggle the contenteditable attribute.

Comment: Will try this,  however without edit button, by just making the task editable, delete button doesnt work, it becomes editable too. Maybe I am missing something, will try make contenteditable with a function when clicking edit

Answer (score 0):

### Update

I attempted to edit the OP code once again and ended up with almost the same code. It's slightly neater and more compact and efficient. Keep in mind you can't take pieces of this code and expect it to work. If it works on the snippet it'll most certainly work elsewhere if copied in its entirety and not pasted into other code.

### Problem

It looks like the references you were using within the submit handler are not accessible from the outside (as it should be). That might be why you're hitting the wall. At the end of the `editing()` function is this:

```
editButton.textContent = 'save';
```

That fouls up everything because `editButton` exists only in the first function. Fortunately all you need to do is replace `editButton` with `this`

```
this.textContent = 'Save';
```

There were some minor problems like the adding of a non-standard attribute named `"li"` with the value of `"readonly"` which if made into an attribute would only be applicable to form controls and editable tags.

- Added `<p>`, and a hidden save `<button>` to the `<li>`
- Added the text to `<p>`
- When in edit mode, the `<p>` gets `contenteditable` attribute enabled
- The save button is revealed and the edit button hidden
- When user is done editing and clicks the save button, `contenteditable` is removed and the edit button is revealed and save button is hidden.

```js
const todo = document.forms.todo;

todo.addEventListener('submit', addTask);

function addTask(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const IO = this.elements;
  const data = IO.task.value;
  const list = document.querySelector('ol');
  const item = document.createElement('li');
  const text = document.createElement('p');
  text.textContent = data;
  IO.task.value = "";
  item.append(text);
  list.append(item);

  const dumpBtn = document.createElement('button')
  dumpBtn.textContent = "Delete";
  dumpBtn.type = 'button';
  item.append(dumpBtn);
  dumpBtn.addEventListener('click', dumpTask)

  const editBtn = document.createElement('button');
  editBtn.textContent = "Edit";
  editBtn.type = 'button';
  item.append(editBtn);
  editBtn.addEventListener('click', editTask);

  const saveBtn = document.createElement('button');
  saveBtn.textContent = 'Save';
  saveBtn.type = 'button';
  saveBtn.classList.add('hide');
  item.append(saveBtn);
  saveBtn.addEventListener('click', saveEdit);
}

function dumpTask(e) {
  this.parentElement.remove();
}

function editTask(e) {
  const item = this.parentElement;
  const text = item.firstElementChild;
  text.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
  this.classList.add('hide');
  this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('hide');
}

function saveEdit(e) {
  const item = this.parentElement;
  const text = item.firstElementChild;
  text.removeAttribute('contenteditable');
  this.classList.add('hide');
  this.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('hide');
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 300 2ch/1.2 'Segoe UI';
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

input,
button {
  font: inherit;
}

button {
  margin: 0 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li {
  height: 2.4rem;
}

li::marker {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1
}

li * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

li p {
  padding: 2px 6px 3.5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

[contenteditable] {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: gold;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>to-DO list</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="todo">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>ToDO</legend>
      <input id='task' type="text" placeholder="Write a task..." required>
      <button>Add</button>
      <ol></ol>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: edit button still doesnt work, with this code i cannot add a task at all, however by implementing some ideas from your code into mine, edit doesnt work.

Comment: You can't take pieces of it and add it to other code. You need to change the names of variables and functions, and the HTML is slightly different as well. The flow and general structure is from OP, it's more organized, efficient, and consistent in style and syntax. Which ideas did you try implementing? It's kinda hard to get my ideas to work properly if certain steps are skipped I try to make my examples work by standards without external dependencies or partial browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, I cant really understand yet how toggle works. Its syntax and its use. So what I did to solve this, was implement all of your suggestions. The code that worked for me was:

```
const addButton = document.querySelector('#addButton');
const inputTask = document.querySelector('#inputTask');
const taskList = document.querySelector('#taskList');
const form = document.querySelector('#taskForm');

// what is left is:
// add a complete button for each task or when click on task add a straight line



form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const task = inputTask.value;
    if (!task) {
        alert('Please write down a task');
    } else {
        const newLi = document.createElement('li');
        const para = document.createElement('para'); // NEW ADD
        const menu = document.createElement('menu')    
        newLi.append(para);
        newLi.append(menu);
        para.textContent = task;
        taskList.append(newLi);
        para.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
        // this is the delete button:
        const deleteButton = document.createElement('button')
        deleteButton.textContent = "delete";
        deleteButton.type = 'button'
        menu.appendChild(deleteButton);
        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', deleting)

        // this is the edit button:

        const editButton = document.createElement('button');
        editButton.textContent= "Edit";
        editButton.type = 'button';
        menu.appendChild(editButton);
        editButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            para.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
            let saveButton = document.createElement('button');
            saveButton.textContent = 'Save';
            editButton.replaceWith(saveButton);
            saveButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
                para.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
                saveButton.replaceWith(editButton);
            });
        });
        
    };
    inputTask.value = "" ; 
    
 });

// delete button make up

function deleting(){
    this.closest('li').remove();
};
```